# Replace all white vertices with color of my choice Blender

Tags: python, vertex-colors

I need a way to replace all white vertices in the scene with color of my choice via python or tools.

The real problems is that I make models with vertex colors and I apply Cell Fracture. Unfortunately all the fractured internal faces are white and I am looking a fast way to replace all the white vertices with a color of my choice.

I am a python noob but I have found so far: [Generate/Replace Vertex Colors](https://github.com/JacRossiter/Jaks_Blender_Scripts/blob/master/Vertex%20Color/Blue_vcols.py) and [invert vertex colors in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44817/how-to-invert-vertex-colors-in-blender)

Comment: Can you show some sample code of what you have so far?

Comment: You can use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135479/edit) below your question to add more relevant information. Commenting on your own question without using @<username> isn't a good idea, because people won't get notified about the update. Please read the [BSE help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about how and why some questions get deleted and how to improve your own question in a way, that others can benefit from it.

Comment: @Sazerac I am a python noob but I have found so far: [Generate/Replace Vertex Colors](https://github.com/JacRossiter/Jaks_Blender_Scripts/blob/master/Vertex%20Color/Blue_vcols.py) and [invert vertex colors in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44817/how-to-invert-vertex-colors-in-blender)